# ReactJS Json Object array

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am having an issue mapping some JSON:

> https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/?county=Lincolnshire

Would really appreciate the help, thanks

I am using the following code to attempt to map the json object

```
await fetch('https://environment.data.gov.uk/flood-monitoring/id/floodAreas/?county=Lincolnshire')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({
      hasLoaded: true,
      weatherItems: json
    })
  });

static renderFloodTable(weatherItems) {
  return (
    <table class="centerTable" className='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tabelLabel">
      <thead>
        <tr>    
          <th>County. (C)</th>           
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {weatherItems.items.map(item =>
          <tr key={item.fwdCode}>                                          
            <td>{item.fwdCode}</td>
          </tr>
        )}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: replace `weatherItems.object.items` with `this.state.weatherItems.items`

Comment: i have tried this but no difference :(

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Does `this.state.weatherItems` output the result of the fetch?

Comment: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Please remember to read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and make sure to look at your post after you post it. Your code is all over the place, please just copy-paste it into a code editor, ask that to auto-format the code, and then paste it back in.

Comment: We need more context to understand what is going on. My suspicion is that you haven't initialised `this.state.weatherItems` to an appropriate value, so that `this.state.weatherItems.items` is indeed `undefined` until the API call has completed. But I can't say for sure without seeing your code.

Comment: Probably won't fix your issue - but I suggest avoiding using both `await` and `then` syntax - just stick with `await` as it's easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

i think the rendering in calling too soon so the `weatherItems` is'nt set yet. try this:

`{weatherItems ? weatherItems.items.map( // ... etc... // ) : null}`

and btw, you should not use `await` And `.then` toogether... choose one...